# Need convert VC code to Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, visual-c++

I need call a DLL file in my delphi code, here is the code snippet of the DLL Head file:

```
#define BookInfoDLL __declspec(dllexport)

struct _BookTime
{
    unsigned char day;
    unsigned char month;
    unsigned short year;
};

struct _stBookData
{
    unsigned char encrypt;
    _BookTime bkTime;
    unsigned int  PageCount;
};

int BookInfoDLL UpdateBooks(const char * const pBookID, 
  const char cBookTypeWord, 
  const _stBookData * const pBookData, 
  const int nBookDataCounter);
```

I need invoke the dll function "UpdateBooks" in my delphi code.
How can I convert those code into delphi? Thank you!

Comment: What is sizeof(_BookTime) and sizeof(_stBookData) ? Records are packed or aligned to machine word boundary ?

Comment: Leo, which part of the translation are you having trouble with? Asking for *this specific* code to be translated puts this question in danger of being closed as "too localized." The general worldwide audience doesn't care how to translate this particular code. Maybe you wonder what "struct" means, or what Delphi type "unsigned char" corresponds to, or what that macro does, or what effect all those "const" modifiers have. Ask a question that might readily be applied to *some other* C++ code as well as this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippet for non-managed Delphi code (not tested, but compiles and changed according suggestions in comments):

```
interface

type

  TBookTime = packed record
    day   : byte; // unsigned 8-bit  
    month : byte;
    year  : word; // unsigned 16-bit
   end;

  TBookData = packed record
    encrypt   : byte;
    bkTime    : TBookTime;
    PageCount : LongWord;   // unsigned 32-bit
  end;

  TBookDataPtr = ^TBookData;

function UpdateBooks(
           pBookID          : PChar;
           cBookTypeWord    : byte;
           pBookData        : TBookDataPtr;
           nBookDataCounter : integer
         ) : integer; stdcall; external 'dll_file_name.dll' name 'UpdateBooks';

implementation

 // ... 

end;
```

Simple call `UpdateBooks(...)`  from delphi code.

---

**Update:** code changed, thanks for commenting!

Below is snippets for sample calls ...

Common functions and constants for all snippets:

```
// --- Test data fill utility and constants -----------------------------------

const
  BOOK_ID         = 'Test Book ID';
  BOOK_TYPE_WORD  = 'T';
  BOOK_DATA_COUNT = 5;

procedure FillTestBookData(pBookData : TBookDataPtr; iTestNum : integer);
begin
  if(pBookData = nil) then exit;

  pBookData^.encrypt := iTestNum;
  pBookData^.bkTime.day := iTestNum;
  pBookData^.bkTime.month := iTestNum;
  pBookData^.bkTime.year := 2000 + iTestNum;
  pBookData^.PageCount := iTestNum;

end;
```

Calling function in common Delphi style:

```
// --- Test procedure in Delphi style -----------------------------------------

procedure TestBookUpdate_DelphiStyle;
var
  bookArray   : array of TBookData;
  iBookNumber : integer;
begin

  SetLength(bookArray, BOOK_DATA_COUNT);
  try

    for iBookNumber := Low(bookArray) to High(bookArray) do begin
      FillTestBookData( @(bookArray[iBookNumber]), iBookNumber );
    end;

    UpdateBooks( 
      PChar(BOOK_ID), ord(BOOK_TYPE_WORD), 
      @(bookArray[Low(bookArray)]), BOOK_DATA_COUNT 
    );

  finally
    SetLength(bookArray, 0); // no explicit requirement to include in code
  end;

end;
```

Bonus: same test calls in C-style and Pascal-style :-)

```
// --- Test procedure in Old Delphi (plain Pascal) style ----------------------

type
  TBookDataOldArray = array[0..0] of TBookData;
  TBookDataOldArrayPtr = ^TBookDataOldArray;

// Store range checking compiler option state
{$IFOPT R+}
  {$DEFINE RANGE_CHECK_ON}
{$ENDIF}

procedure TestBookUpdate_OldDelphiStyle;
var
  bookArrayPtr : TBookDataOldArrayPtr;
  iBookNumber  : integer;
begin

  GetMem(bookArrayPtr, BOOK_DATA_COUNT*sizeof(TBookData));
  try
    // Disable range checking compiler option
    {$R-}

    for iBookNumber := 0 to BOOK_DATA_COUNT - 1 do begin
      FillTestBookData(@(bookArrayPtr^[iBookNumber]), iBookNumber);
    end;

    // Restore range checking compiler option if turned on before disabling
    {$IFDEF RANGE_CHECK_ON}{$R+}{$ENDIF}

    UpdateBooks(
      PChar(BOOK_ID), ord(BOOK_TYPE_WORD), TBookDataPtr(bookArrayPtr), BOOK_DATA_COUNT
    );

  finally
    FreeMem(bookArrayPtr);
  end;

end;

// --- Test procedure in C style ---------------------------------------------

procedure TestBookUpdate_CStyle;
var
  bookArrayPtr  : TBookDataPtr;
  curBookPtr    : TBookDataPtr;
  curBookNumber : integer;
begin

  bookArrayPtr := AllocMem( BOOK_DATA_COUNT * sizeof(TBookData) );
  try
    curBookNumber := 0;
    curBookPtr := bookArrayPtr;
    while(curBookNumber < BOOK_DATA_COUNT) do begin
      FillTestBookData( curBookPtr, curBookNumber );
      inc(curBookNumber);
      inc(curBookPtr, 1);
      // Another pointer increment solution is :
      // curBookPtr := PChar(curBookPtr) + sizeof(TBookData);
    end;

    UpdateBooks( PChar(BOOK_ID), ord(BOOK_TYPE_WORD), bookArrayPtr, BOOK_DATA_COUNT );

  finally
    FreeMem(bookArrayPtr);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: The param "pBookdata" may hold more than one TBookData struct, "nBookDataCounter" point out the number of TBookData struct.

Comment: Leo, that isn't *necessarily* a problem with ThinkJet's translation, but it will make the function calls look a little strange. You'll have an array, but you'll pass just the first element to the function: `UpdateBooks(..., BookData[0], Length(BookData))`. ThinkJet, it's better to just translate pointer parameters in C++ into pointer parameters in Delphi.

Comment: Alignment of records? Probably needs to be packed. Also I think drop all CONST except pbookdata because for that one a dereference (*) was dropped.

Comment: Thanks for all commentators! Code changed according to comments, you are welcome to review it another time! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [h2pas](http://www.freepascal.org/tools/h2pas.var)! Although it is a freepascal tool, it should produce Delphi compatible code.

Answer (score 1):

I have ended my first C header conversion yesterday. The articles and tools from TeamB member Rudy Velthuis were very, very helpful for me, specially

[Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)

[Conversion Helper Package](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html)